# Accessing data retuned by PowerShell Import-CSV

Tags: csv, powershell, office365

I am trying to write a PowerShell script that uses a CSV file as input that will turn off the clutter feature in Office 365. The CSV file has only 1 column and that has the 2 target email addresses that I am using for testing. When I run this script with a read-host line and enter a valid email address it works with no errors. When I use the CSV file errors follow.

```
Import-Module MSOnline
$LiveCred = Get-Credential 
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/PowerShell  -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection 
Import-PSSession -allowclobber $Session

Connect-MsolService -Credential $LiveCred
cd c:\scripts

Write-Host "This tool removes the Clutter feature from O365 "

$Clutter = Import-Csv .\Clutteroff.csv

foreach ($user in $Clutter){
    Set-Clutter -Identity $User -Enable $false
}
```

When I run this I get the following error :

> Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'. Cannot convert value "@{UserID=xxxxx@myCompany.com}" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter". Error: "Cannot 
>   convert hashtable to an object of the following type: Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.MailboxIdParameter. Hashtable-to-Object conversion is not supported in restricted language mode or a Data 
>   section."

```
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Clutter], ParameterBindin...mationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Set-Clutter
+ PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com
```

Any help would be appreciated and explanations will get extra credit :)

CSV file = User, XXXX@MyCompany.com, YYYY@MyCompany.com

Email addresses are valid.

Comment: Is your CSV only the one _column_?

Comment: `Set-Clutter -Identity $User.UserID -Enable $false` possibly if I can read into your CSV structure. It looks like your -Identity is an object with a userid property. You need to extract the property from the object. You also have an empty `-Header` which might be a typo.

Comment: -header is a typo from previous attempts to fix the script. So the CSV structure is really simple for this test. The five was built in excel and has 3 entries. These entries are my groups email addresses in cells 1A, 2A, 3A and then saved as a CSV file. $User was just supposed to = the text in 1A, 2A....

Comment: What about my other comments? Did you try my suggestions?

Comment: I was off site and have not setup this from my home machine. I will be trying this today. Thanks for your input and I will certainly post the results.

Comment: @Matt Unfortunately the $User.UserID mod did not work. This ended up generating the following error x3 (for the 3 users in the CSV file)       >Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Set-Clutter], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Set-Clutter
    + PSComputerName        : ps.outlook.com<

Comment: Is your csv one line or one column? The error in the question shows you have a header of `userid` which us why I made my suggestion. Interpetting your source data is clearly the issue

Answer (score 1):

Putting all of the items in one line like that is not going to work well with Import-CSV.  Import-CSV is suited to a table structure (columns and rows), whereas you are just using a comma-separated list (one row, with an unknown number of columns).  If in fact you *do* have the items on different lines, then please correct the question and I'll change the answer.

To work with the data from a file formatted like that, I would just split it into an ArrayList, and remove the first item because it is "User" and not not an email address:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Clutter = (get-content .\Clutteroff.csv).split(",")
$Clutter.RemoveAt(0)
```

Then you can iterate through the array:

```
foreach ($user in $Clutter){
    $address = $user.trim()
    {Set-Clutter -Identity $address -Enable $false}
}
```

For the extra credit, `$user` in your script was returning a row of key/value pairs to represent columns (keys) and the data in the columns (values).  Your error message shows @{UserID=xxxxx@myCompany.com}, so to return just the email address you would use `$user.UserID` to return the value for UserID.

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the reply but I tried this and it doesn't seem to work. Now there are no errors, but when I run it the output on the screen is "This tool removes the Clutter feature from O365 
Set-Clutter -Identity $address -Enable $false
Set-Clutter -Identity $address -Enable $false". When I run > Get-Clutter -Identity  $User | FL <  and $User is one of the email addresses in my test it indicates that Clutter is enabled. @Tony Hinkle

Comment: After the `$address = $user.trim()` line, add a line with just `$address` and see if it is returning the email addresses as expected.  The Set-Clutter examples I'm finding don't use email addresses--you may need to use `Get-Mailbox –identity $address | Set-Clutter -enable $false`

Comment: Adding the $address line generates the email addresses for each of the test users, so the variable is populating correctly. An interesting thing is that it is skipping cell A1. It appears that the array solution is still not working. Unfortunately because I'm new at this I did not add Remove-PSSession $Session to the end of my script, so I am now generating errors because I have reached the limit of the sessions I can have open... Would it be good practice to always add Remove-PSSession $Session to the end of a script like this?

Comment: I claim no particular expertise on that matter, but my 25 years of IT experience says "yes."

Comment: Is your CSV file truly one line?  The reason I have it skipping "cell" A1 is because the CSV file example you provided has "User" in cell A1.  If cell A1 has an email address in it, then remove the `$Clutter.RemoveAt(0)` line.

Comment: That is pretty much what i thought the .RemoveAt(0) did, so I appear to be learning :)

Answer (score -1):

i GOT THIS WORKING TO PULL FROM CSV SO ONLY THOSE USERS ARE MODIFIED!! SORRY FOR THE CAPS BUT I AM A TOTAL NOOB AND I COULDNT BELIEVE I GOT THIS TO WORK!!! I am beyond STOKED!! :)

the csv requires no headers, just the email address of the users you want to modify in one column

```
$Clutter = (Get-Content "pathofyourcsv.csv")
foreach ($User in $Clutter) {
    $address = $User
    Get-Mailbox -Identity $User | Set-Clutter -Enable $false}
```

Comment: Hi Everyone, here is an updated, nicer looking version LOL $Clutter = (Get-Content "pathofyourcsv.csv")
foreach ($User in $Clutter) {
  Set-Clutter -Identity $User -Enable $false}